# how to let flutter appbar to show the time clock and network of phone

Tags: flutter

Now I am using appbar in flutter but it override the phone's time\network\battery, what should I do to make it shows, this is my appbar code:

```
child: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverOverlapAbsorber(
                handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(
                  context,
                ),
                sliver: SliverAppBar(
                  title: Text(
                    'Cruise',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.light
                          ? Colors.black
                          : Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  pinned: true,
                  floating: true,
                  forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled,
                  actions: [
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddChannel()),
                      ),
                      icon: Icon(Feather.plus),
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
          ];
        },
```

and the UI look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap all of it in a SafeArea. It's a widget that help you automatically avoid notches in the screen and such.
[SafeArea Class documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html)